# Is it possible to have a user draw a graphic in livecode?

Tags: livecode, graphic

For a game I am working on the user must draw a line and an object will follow the line. To me it would be logical for the user's line to be a graphic and then do something like this (the user's line is called "userLine")

```
move the image "xyz" to the points of graphic "userLine"
```

is it possible to have the user draw a graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `choose` command. This should get you started.

To start out drawing your line:
(This could be in a a button script, for example. However you want to trigger the user drawing.)

```
if there is a graphic "userLine" then
    delete graphic "userLine"
end if
set the style of the templateGraphic to "line"
set the selectionHandleColor to the effective backgroundcolor of this card
choose graphic tool
```

Then in the card script add the following handler:

```
on newGraphic
   choose browse tool
   set the selectionHandleColor to black
   set the name of graphic (the number of graphics) to "userLine"
   move btn "radio" to the points of grc "userLine" in 2 seconds
end newGraphic
```

Some variation of this should work.

Comment: Is there a way to make the graphic type freehand?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, Jeff. Do you mean changing the type of graphic automatically, or drawing more of a freehand line?